# odbc_exec - no error or results

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm new to using odbc functions.  I'm trying to simply execute a simple query, but I get not error or results back.  I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
$server = [hidden];
$database = [hidden];
$user = [hidden];
$password = [hidden];
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);

if ($connection) {
    $mail = 'email@email.com';
    $queryc = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Found] FROM [Table].[dbo].[Persons] WHERE [Address] = '$mail'";
    $resultsc = odbc_exec($connection, $queryc);
    if( !$resultsc ) {
        die( print_r( odbc_error())));
    } else {
        'hi!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Two suggestions: check the PHP error log and throw this code at the top of all your code: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: You seem to be trying to use a parameterized query here, kudos for that. However, your query has the string literal '$mail' in the where predicate. You need to find a tutorial on using parameterized queries in PHP.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` on top of your code just after `<?php` and check by running the code that any error shown or not?

Comment: I tried adding the error reporting and ini_set and nothing shows up.

Comment: What do you mean by string literal?

Comment: You are referencing the literal string '$mail', that doesn't reference your $mail variable. So your SQL string is literally `SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Found] FROM [Table].[dbo].[Persons] WHERE [Address] = '$mail'` and you want it to be `SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Found] FROM [Table].[dbo].[Persons] WHERE [Address] = 'email@email.com'`

Comment: Check this site for some help on parameterizing queries: http://bobby-tables.com/php

Comment: Here's an example: `$stmt = odbc_prepare( $conn, 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?' );
$success = odbc_execute( $stmt, array($email) );`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem.  It was fixed doing this:

```
$server = [hidden];
$database = [hidden];
$user = [hidden];
$password = [hidden];
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);

if ($connection) {
    $mail = 'email@email.com';
    $queryc = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Found] FROM [Table].[dbo].[Persons] WHERE [Address] = '$mail'";
    $resultsc = odbc_exec($connection, $queryc) or die(odbc_errormsg());
    if( $resultsc ) {
        'hi!';
    }
}
```